# How to determine a disk consuming service in Windows 2008 server?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, hard-drive, cleanup

How to determine a disk consuming service in Windows 2008 server? I have a problem on Windows 2008 server with a constant growing used disk space? How to determine which service consuming most of the disk? How to clean-up that disk? I have used Windows build-in program, "disk clean-up" but does not "find" those "growing" files? I am suspicions of the some logging service ... On the server is 40 GB disk, if I select all files on the C: disk and look properties, I get 12 GB (I have check option to see hidden files). Where are the difference? Where can I see the other 28 GB?

Comment: This might be helpful in understanding things: http://serverfault.com/questions/79485/windows-2008-winsxs-directory-growing-uncontrollably-blocking-server

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would starty by running the free program [windirstat](http://windirstat.info/) against the system drive.  It will provide a graphical view of the folders on your machine, the space they take up, and the filetypes that are consuming the space.

Take a look through the top folders it displays, and look to see if there are files in there that you don't know about.

Once you determine the "where" then Process Monitor or even the old "filemon" from sysinternals can help identify the process that is creating or updating the files.

I also assume that you have removed the microsoft patch "uinistallation' directories in the Windows folders.  Generally, everything in the systemroot\system32 folder that starts with a dollar sign EXCEPT $hf_mig can go...

Hope this helps,

Glenn

Comment: This is it! Great! Thanks. With windirstat I have solved a problem in a minute!

Comment: Glad I could help.  WinDirStat is one of my regular "go-to" programs.  It is a bit of a RAM hog while scanning, but when you are short on disc space, low available RAM is the least of your problems...